# Cakephp REST API - put and delete not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, cakephp

Hi i have a simple jquery codes that request a put to cakephp

```
$("#putBtn").click(function(){
    var id = $("#searchTxt").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/cakephp/recipes/'+id,
        type: 'PUT',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
            name:"777",
            number:"777"
        },
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

problem is that when the run this command and send it to cakephp 
it make an error of this

/cakephp/recipes/1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. jquery-2.1.0.js:8556
error

in my cakephp i just follow this tutorial 
//book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

```
public function edit($id) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
    $this->viewClass = 'json';
    if ($this->Recipe->save($this->data)) {
        $message = 'Saved';
    } else {
        $message = 'Error';
    }
    $this->set(array(
        'message' => $message,
        '_serialize' => array('message')
    ));
}
```

i also added the router.php with

```
Router::resourceMap(array(
    array('action' => 'index', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => false),
    array('action' => 'view', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => true),
    array('action' => 'add', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => false),
    array('action' => 'edit', 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => true),
    array('action' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => true),
    array('action' => 'update', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => true)
));

Router::mapResources('recipes');
Router::parseExtensions();
```

i dont know why cakephp is not accepting my request of PUT or DELETE command.
any suggestions or advice ? .or what im i doing wrong . thx in advance .

Comment: You cannot send XHR requests to a different <Domain>:<port> combination other that the one present in the url of the page. I am guessing the page url has a port other than the default 80..

Comment: `url: 'http://localhost/cakephp/recipes/'+id,` <- use a relative url.

Comment: what if the url is in a different ip address ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with **CakePHP version 2.5.4** for parsing a PUT call.

Not elegant, but this did work.

**Front End Code:**

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
          type      : 'PUT',
          url       : '/projects/foo',
          dataType  : 'json',
          data      : JSON.stringify({
              'projectId'   : 789,
              'desc'        : "cheese cake",
          }),
          success: function(return_data) {
            alert("success");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(return_data));
          },
          error: function(return_data) {
            alert("error");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(return_data));
          });
});
```

**Back-end Code (app/Controller/ProjectsController.php)**

```
public function foo() {

        $this->autoRender = false;

        if($this->request->is('PUT')) {

            $in = $this->request->data;
            reset($in);
            $in = json_decode(key($in), true);

            $project_id = $in['projectId'];
            $desc = $in['desc'];
        }

        $response = array(
            'project_id'    => $project_id,
            'desc'          => $desc,
            );

        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
}
```

**Result:**

Check your console when you test this code.  It will just send back what you sent over in the first place, but will give you the assurance that your back-end code in CakePHP can now parse these JSON PUT requests.